# Error Cisco Prime HTTP GET request

Tags: perl

I'm trying to make an HTTP GET request with Cisco Prime:

```
#!/opt/local/bin/perl -w

use strict;

use JSON-support_by_pp;
use LWP 5.64;
use LWP::UserAgent;

$ENV{PERL_LWP_SSL_VERIFY_HOSTNAME} = 0;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;

my $BASE_URL = 'https://Host_name/webacs/api/v1/';
my $UN       = "Username";
my $PW       = "Password";

sub fetch ($) {
    my ( $url ) = @_;
    my $req = HTTP::Request->new( GET => $BASE_URL . $url );
    $req->authorization_basic( $UN, $PW );
    return $ua->request( $req )->content or die( "Cannot read from " . $BASE_URL . $url );
}

my $content = fetch( 'data/AccessPoints.json?.full=true' );

my $json = new JSON;

# these are some nice json options to relax restrictions a bit:
my $json_text =
        $json->allow_nonref->utf8->relaxed->escape_slash->loose->allow_singlequote->allow_barekey->decode( $content );

foreach my $ap ( @{ $json_text->{queryResponse}->{'entity'} } ) {

    print "------------------------\nAccess Point " . $ap->{'accessPointsDTO'}->{'@id'} . "\n";
    print "Model:" . $ap->{'accessPointsDTO'}->{'model'} . "\n";
    print "MAC Address:" . $ap->{'accessPointsDTO'}->{'macAddress'} . "\n";
    print "Serial Number:" . $ap->{'accessPointsDTO'}->{'serialNumber'} . "\n";
    print "Software Version:" . $ap->{'accessPointsDTO'}->{'softwareVersion'} . "\n";
    print "Status:" . $ap->{'accessPointsDTO'}->{'status'} . "\n";
    print "Location:" . $ap->{'accessPointsDTO'}->{'location'} . "\n";
```

What do I do wrong? I have already tried with curl in shell and it works:

```
    curl --tlsv1 --user USER:PASSWORD--insecure https://Host_name/webacs/api/v1/data/AccessPoints.json?.full=true
```

but my Perl script doesn't work.

I have this error:

> malformed JSON string, neither array, object, number, string or atom, at  character offset 0 (before "Can't connect to 10....") at ersteProbe.pl line 28.

Fix already. Thank you Borodin :)

New question:
I need authentication for Cisco Prime.
Code works already, but authentication doesn't work.

I have with error

```
    500 Can't connect to 10.10.10.10:443 (certificate verify failed) at ersteProbeAuth.pl line 27.
```

Line 27:

```
      die $res->status_line unless $res->is_success;
```

I'm rather new in Perl und cann't fix this myself. If you have Idee, I'll be happy :)

```
    #!/opt/local/bin/perl -w
    use strict;
    use warnings;
    use JSON -support_by_pp;
    use LWP 5.64;
    use LWP::UserAgent;
    use MIME::Base64;
    use REST::Client;

    $ENV{PERL_LWP_SSL_VERIFY_HOSTNAME} = 0;
    my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;

    my $BASE_URL = 'https://10.10.10.10/webacs/api/v1/';
    my $UN='admin';
    my $PW='admin';
    # coding with Base 64
    my $sys_id='Balalalalalal';
    my $encoded_auth = encode_base64("$UN:$PW", '');

    sub fetch {
        my ($url) = @_;
        my  $res = $ua->get($BASE_URL . $url,
             {'Authorization' => "Basic $encoded_auth",
              'Accept' => 'application/json'});
       die $res->status_line unless $res->is_success;
       my $json = $res->decoded_content;
       return $json
    }
    my $content = fetch('data/AccessPoints.json?.full=true/$sys_id');
    my $json = new JSON;
    # these are some nice json options to relax restrictions a bit:  my$json_text=$json->allow_nonref->utf8->relaxed->escape_slash->loose->allow_singlequote->allow_barekey->decode($content);
   foreach my $ap (@{$json_text->{queryResponse}->{'entity'}}){
   print "------------------------\nAccess Point ".$ap->{'accessPointsDTO'}->{'@id'}."\n";
   print "Model:".$ap->{'accessPointsDTO'}->{'model'}."\n";
   print "MAC Address:".$ap->{'accessPointsDTO'}->{'macAddress'}."\n";
   print "Serial Number:".$ap->{'accessPointsDTO'}->{'serialNumber'}."\n";
   print "Software Version:".$ap->{'accessPointsDTO'}->{'softwareVersion'}."\n";
   print "Status:".$ap->{'accessPointsDTO'}->{'status'}."\n";
   print "Location:".$ap->{'accessPointsDTO'}->{'location'}."\n";
   }
```

Comment: Your Perl code is a dreadful mess and you can't possibly be confident that it is correct. I have fixed it for you this time so that I could read it, but please post legible code in the future. There is a missing closing brace `}` and it generates the warning `Possible precedence issue with control flow operator` which you didn't tell us about

Comment: Never use Perl subroutine prototypes like `sub fetch ($) { ... }`.They don't do what you think they do, and just `sub fetch { ... }` is correct.

Comment: It was really silly with missing closing brace `}`
Sorry for that.
Can you please look thouth my  authentication?

Comment: That is a separate issue and should be posted as a new question. But take a look at [*`LWP::UserAgent` and Basic Authentication*](https://perlmaven.com/lwp-useragent-and-basic-authentication). By the way, please add new information—especially code—by editing the question; it's all but impossible to read in a comment.

Comment: Already done.
But in this case should I post new question or just edit my old question?

Comment: Thank you. You need to open a new question. And please indent your code properly.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what's wrong without access to the web page, but almost certainly your request has failed

I suggest you replace your `fetch` subroutine with this

```
sub fetch {
    my ( $url ) = @_;

    my $res = $ua->get( $BASE_URL . $url );
    die $res->status_line unless $res->is_success;

    my $json = $res->decoded_content;

    return $json;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Print your raw answer from server in console.

malformed JSON string, neither array, object, number, string or atom, at  character offset 0 (before "Can't connect to 10....")

> "Can't connect to 10...."

Maybe, your code is not have connect